# VBA to copy excel sheet and create new work book at the beginning of every month

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA macro to create a copy of excel worksheet everyday, and name the sheet with the date, I will copy the code below, it works just fine.
However, I am trying to improve the macro so that at the beginning of every month, a new work book is created. To do that, I create a copy of the current work book when the day of the date = 1, delete all worksheets from the previous month, and start copying for the new month.
This macro creates a work book at the beginning of every month and deletes all the previous worksheets, however, when it copies the sheets it creates two copies of every sheet (this happens only when it goes through the if condition, otherwise if we are in the middle of the month, it works fine), which is frustrating, I have tried to understand the issue but I am not able to figure it out.
I would appreciate it if anyone have any idea how to resolve the issue, or know of an alternative way to make the macro do the required task

This is the code that only copies the sheets (Works perfectly)

```
        Sub AdddayWkst()
'**Declaring variables and their types**
Dim wsM As Worksheet '*Master worksheet*
Dim strName As String '*String name = work sheet name*
Dim wsMDate As Date '*Master worksheet date*
Dim todayDate As Date  '*Current date*
Dim intYear As Integer '*Year of master worksheet date*
Dim intMonth As Integer '*Month of master worksheet date*
Dim intDay As Integer '*Day of master worksheet date*


On Error Resume Next '*command to prevent crashing, so in case of error, skip the line that is causing the error and perform the next command*
Set wsM = Worksheets(1) '*Set the leftmost (most recent) sheet to the variable wsM*
wsMDate = CDate(Worksheets(1).name) '*Convert the name of the leftmost (master) worksheet into date format*
todayDate = Date '*Set the current date in todayDate parameter*
intYear = Year(wsMDate) '*Save the year of master sheet in intYear*
intMonth = Month(wsMDate) '*Save the Month of master sheet in intMonth*
intDay = Day(wsMDate) '*Save the Day of master sheet in intDay* Needed to increment the days
strName = Format(DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1), "mm-dd-yyyy") '*increment the date of the original master sheet by 1 day, save it in strName to be used as the name of the new copied sheet*
TimeSheet (wsMDate) '*run the function timesheet to update the time sheet* Function details are below

Do While wsMDate < todayDate '*repeat the instructions inside this loop as long as the date of the master sheet (leftmost sheet) is less than the current date*
        wsM.Copy before:=Sheets(1) '*Copy the Master worksheet and place the copy before the leftmost sheet*
        set wsM = ActiveSheet '*the new copy is now set as the master sheet*
        'wsM = Worksheets(1)
        wsMDate = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1) '*increase the date by one day to prepare for the next copy until this date is equal to the current date
        strName = Format(DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1), "mm-dd-yyyy") '*the name is also incremented by one day and set to the desired format
        'Cells(2, 16) = strName
        intYear = Year(wsMDate) '*update the year value after increasing the date
        intMonth = Month(wsMDate) '*update the month value after increasing the date
        intDay = Day(wsMDate) '*update the day value after increasing the date
        ActiveSheet.name = strName '*set the name of the new copy to (strName) value
        TimeSheet (wsMDate) '*run the time sheet function to update the time sheet in every copied sheet
Loop

Set wsM = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is the code that is supposed to create a new book at the beginning of each month:

```
Sub AdddayWkst()
'**Declaring variables and their types**
Dim wsM As Worksheet '*Master work sheet*
Dim xWs As Worksheet '*Deleted work sheet*
Dim strName As String '*String name = work sheet name*
Dim strMonthB As Integer '*Month before incrementing the day*'
Dim strMonthA As Integer '*Month after incremnting the day*'
Dim wsMDate As Date '*Master worksheet date*
Dim todayDate As Date '*Current date*'
Dim intYear As Integer '*Year of master worksheet date*
Dim intMonth As Integer '*Month of master worksheet date*
Dim intDay As Integer '*Day of master worksheet date*
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant



On Error Resume Next '*command to prevent crashing, so in case of error, skip the line and perform the next command*
Set wsM = Worksheets(1) '*Set the leftmost (most recent) sheet to the variable wsM*
wsMDate = CDate(wsM.Name) '*Convert the name of the leftmost (master) worksheet into date format*
todayDate = Date '*Set the current date in todayDate parameter*
intYear = Year(wsMDate) '*Save the year of master sheet in intYear*
intMonth = Month(wsMDate) '*Save the Month of master sheet in intMonth*
intDay = Day(wsMDate) '*Save the Day of master sheet in intDay* Needed to increment the days
strMonthB = intMonth '*Save the month of the leftmost sheet as the month before incrementing* Needed to detemine if new book is needed
strName = Format(DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1), "mm-dd-yyyy") '*increment the date of the original master sheet by 1, save it in strName to be used as the name of the new copied sheet*
strMonthA = Month(CDate(strName)) '*convert strName to date format and get the month of it* Comparing this month to the (strMonthB) before month to determine if new month started; hence a new workbook need to be created
'Cells(2, 20) = strMonthB
'Cells(2, 21) = strMonthA
'Cells(2, 21) = strName
'Cells(3, 21) = wsMDate
'Cells(20, 20) = strName

a = DateDiff("d", wsMDate, Now)
For b = 1 To a '*repeat the instructions inside this loop as long as the date of the master sheet (leftmost sheet) is less than the current date*
'Cells(2, 22) = strName
'Cells(3, 22) = wsMDate


        If strMonthA > strMonthB And Day(CDate(strName)) = 1 Then '*If a new month starts then perform the below commands*

        Set wsM = Worksheets(1)
        'Cells(2, 23) = strName
        'Cells(3, 23) = wsMDate
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\Documents\xxx.xlsm" '*Create a copy of the current workbook in the specified directory*
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\xxx.xlsm" '*Open the new workbook*
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False '*Stop popup messages* Needed to prevent Excel from asking for confirmation to delete sheets
        'wsM.Copy before:=Workbooks("C:\Users\Documents\xxx.xlsm").Sheets(1)
        'wsM.Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
        For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '*go through each and every sheet in the newly copied workbook*
        If Month(CDate(xWs.Name)) <> Month(todayDate) Then '*if the montth of the sheet does not equal the current month, delete that sheet*
            xWs.Delete
        End If
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True '*Allow popup messages once again*
        'wsM.Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
        End If
        
        wsM.Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
        Set wsM = Worksheets(1)
        strMonthB = intMonth '*update the month value with each iteration*
        'Cells(2, 24) = strName
        'Cells(3, 24) = wsMDate
        wsMDate = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1) '*increment the days with 1 with each iteration*
        strName = Format(DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay + 1), "mm-dd-yyyy") '*name of sheet also incremented with each iteration*
        strMonthA = Month(CDate(strName)) '*update the month after incrementing the day*
        'Cells(2, 20) = strMonthB
        'Cells(2, 21) = strMonthA
        'Cells(3, 20) = wsMonth
        'Cells(3, 21) = Month(todayDate)
        'Cells(2, 16) = strName
        'Cells(3, 25) = wsMDate
        intYear = Year(wsMDate)
        intMonth = Month(wsMDate)
        intDay = Day(wsMDate)
        ActiveSheet.Name = strName '*Set the name of the active sheet to be the strName*


Next

Set wsM = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: workking with specific formats like dates in vba can be cumberstone as the operating system or your data may be set for a specific format like yyyy-mm-dd, vba will implicitly convert it into another format and a script might seem to work until day 12 and after nothing will happen because vba considers day as month and expects a number below 12 when it's a day.That might explain why the script is working during a period and acting strange in another period

Comment: That's a valid point, but I don't think it is the issue here, Since the copying works just fine even after day 12 (the code only gives an issue when entering the if condition)

Comment: If you could provide a sample of the data where the issue is and another sample where it works, it would be easier to see the issue

Comment: my request is because if you write dates in a specific way 2012-01-21 or 01/21/2012 or 21-21-2012... i don't know we can spend lot of time looking for someting that is data related and vba adds another layer of difficulty with its proprietaty way of dealing with data types such as dates